# Jqgrid - Date Column formatting

Tags: jqgrid, date-format

The date coulmn  that is returned in json is 1371700800000. I'm trying to convert it to mm/dd/yyyy format .

I have the code below to format in the jqgrid , but still getting the value of the date as NaN/NaN/NaN. I'm using jqgrid version 4.4.1. Please help.

```
 {name:'inactiveDate',index:'inactiveDate', width:30, formatter:'date',  formatoptions: {srcformat:"d/m/Y H:i A", newformat: 'ShortDate' },editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions: {size: 10, maxlengh: 10,dataInit : function (elem) {
                    $(elem).datepicker();
                }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the NaN/NaN/NaN issue for date-field by manually altering the jquery.jqgrid.src.js (4.5.2).
In my case, the json response would return date in an 'ISO1860Long'. It used to work till the 4.1.2 jqgrid version

Search for "parseDate" function; goto the line after :

```
if( opts.masks.hasOwnProperty(format) ) { format = opts.masks[format]; }
if(date && date != null) {
```

and add the below if check :

```
if(date.constructor === Number) {
  if(String(format).toLowerCase() == "u") {
    date = date*1000;
  }
  timestamp = new Date(date);
} else
```

before the existing :

```
if( !isNaN( date - 0 ) && String(format).toLowerCase() === "u") {
```

you can translate the changes to jquery.jqgrid.min.js  yourself IF needed

Answer (score 0):

Date format `mm/dd/yyyy` is displayed in jqGrid like `0404/2828/16161616`, you should use this format `m/d/y` and it is displayed as `04/28/16`. Single m or d or y is enough otherwise it repeats double.

**Note:** For convert long date in jqGrid mention `U/1000` at **srcformat** in **formatoptions** function.

**Code:**

```
{name:'startDate',index:'startDate',width:120, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'U/1000', newformat:'m/d/Y' }},
```

**Output In jqGrid Column:** `04/28/16`

**Code:**

```
{name:'startDate',index:'startDate',width:120, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'U/1000', newformat:'d-M-Y H:i A' }},
```

**Output In jqGrid Column:** `28-Apr-2016 08:30 AM`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue I have solved directly when check date is null or defined something else I had set condtion and directly return funcion it works proper.

please go to `parseDate` function

befor this logic undestand the code logic.

> if (date && date != null) {

```
        if(date != '' && date == 'N.A'){
            return 'N.A';
        }
```